# SimpleBlobDetection opencv C++ setting parameters issue with symbols

Tags: c++, opencv, parameters, detection

I am trying to implement the SimpleBlobDetector into one of my programs and I am having trouble deciphering the error message I am receiving.
I am asking for any hints as to what this error means, I am extremely unfamiliar with Visual Studio.

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params::Params(void)" (??0Params@SimpleBlobDetector@cv@@QAE@XZ)

Visual studio is reading the correct class and struct so the issue isn't in the library.

The following is the line of code that initially gives me errors.

```
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
```

Setting all the parameters works fine and I haven't tried initiating the blob detecting object because I need the parameters to do that.

A little background:

I have code that performs background subtraction on incoming frames(video) and I wanted to take this and perform blob detection on each frame in a relatively simple manner.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. For anyone else that encounters a similar issue, you are just missing libraries. Reinstall open cv or look up how to link the necessary libs.

Comment: what all libraries are required to include ? i'm getting the same error

Comment: This was right when I decided to give programming a shot heh.No idea at this point but I am assuming I had the system misconfigured. 
Configuration for this is quite a chaotic pain.  -1 to my past self for my disappointing answer.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=vs-2019